# how to search a string using argumnet

Tags: python, mysql

I was trying to pass the query to mysql database
here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

sql = "select count(distinct offering),count(learner),count(distinct learner),sum(transaction ) from EMS_data where offering like 'engineering'  and manager='patel' and fiscal like %s" % sys.argv[1]
```

In the fiscal column i had entered 
2010
2011
2012
2013

In the command line I had typed the filename and 2013. But its showing me this result

```
mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column '2013' in 'where clause'")
```

i was not searching for the column but contains inside the column.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [MySQLdb's prepared statements](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/) as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test623', 'testdb')

with con:    

    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute("UPDATE Writers SET Name = %s WHERE Id = %s", 
        ("Guy de Maupasant", "4"))        

    print "Number of rows updated:",  cur.rowcount
```

However, your immediate problem can be solved by:

```
sql = "select count(distinct offering),count(learner),count(distinct learner),sum(transaction ) from EMS_data where offering like 'engineering'  and manager='patel' and fiscal regexp '%s'" % sys.argv[1]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.. but the solution didn't help it gives the same result as i'm getting...